# Rotating Google Maps in Ionic project

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using Google Maps API JS in my Ionic project, and everything is fine except that I can't rotate the map, only pan and zoom. So I looked and found this code to be added:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 20,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    rotateControl: true
  };
```

But no change happened. Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Well, there is no problem.  rotateControl works, when your maptype is SATELLITE (push the Satellite button, rotateControl will magically appear).  rotateControl has no meaning when the map is shown as ROADMAP.  Also, try it out on a popular location first (like time square, New York); I think it doesn't work everywhere.

Comment: Maybe the gesture I'm talking about is not rotate. What I mean is the gesture when holding two fingers and rotating clockwise or anticlockwise. This doesn't work, only zooming and panning works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh yes.  Sorry, I don't know how to do that

Comment: @coding4fun Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Even though its 4 year old question, You can do so by using the latest Google Maps plugin from ionic and then use following code

```
let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
  gestures:{
    rotate:false,
    tilt:false,
    scroll:false
  }
};

this.map = this.googleMaps.create(this.mapDiv.nativeElement, mapOptions);
```

Notice the rotate:false gesture in mapOptions. This will help you enable/disable 2 finger rotation of Map.